# Cannot fetch children data from firebase database and post it to activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

so here I am trying to fetch students from the database so that I can be able to take attendance but so far I've tried approaching it with a different logic and still it is not showing anything. So kindly take a look a tell me where I did wrong.
everything is running smoothly just that I cannot fetch students from the database so take it can allow me to mark attendance

```
private String intendUnit, intendDate;
private DatabaseReference studentRef, departmentRef, attendanceRef, presentRef, absentRef;
private String department, faculty;
private List<StudentConstructor> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView listView;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper recyclerViewHelper;
private Button btnSubmit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_attendance);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarTake);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intendUnit = intent.getStringExtra("SU");
    intendDate = intent.getStringExtra("DATE");

    btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnTakeSubmit);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerTakeAttendance);

    studentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Department");
    attendanceRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Department").child("Attendance");
    presentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Department").child("Attendance").child("Present");
    absentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Department").child("Attendance").child("Absent");

    studentRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1:snapshot.getChildren()){
                    department = snapshot1.getKey();
                    departmentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Department").child("Student");
                    departmentRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            studentList.clear();
                            if (snapshot.exists()){
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot2:snapshot.getChildren()){
                                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot3:snapshot2.getChildren()){
                                        if (snapshot3.hasChildren()){
                                            StudentConstructor student = snapshot3.getValue(StudentConstructor.class);
                                            if (student.getUnit().contains(intendDate)){
                                                studentList.add(student);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                recyclerViewHelper = new TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper(getApplicationContext(), studentList);
                                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(TakeAttendanceActivity.this));
                                recyclerViewHelper.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewHelper);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper.presentList.clear();
    TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper.absentList.clear();
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TakeAttendanceActivity.this).create();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(TakeAttendanceActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.attendance_popup, null);
        TextView total, present, absent;
        Button btnConfirm, btnCancel;
        total = view.findViewById(R.id.totalStudent);
        present = view.findViewById(R.id.presentStudent);
        absent = view.findViewById(R.id.absentStudent);
        btnConfirm = view.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        btnCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

        total.setText(Integer.toString(studentList.size()));
        present.setText(Integer.toString(TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper.presentList.size()));
        absent.setText(Integer.toString(TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper.absentList.size()));
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setView(view);

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
            String presentStudentID = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper.presentList.size(); i++){
                presentStudentID = TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper.presentList.get(i);
                presentRef.child(presentStudentID).setValue(presentStudentID);
            }
            String absentStudentID = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper.absentList.size(); i++){
                absentStudentID = TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper.absentList.get(i);
                absentRef.child(absentStudentID).setValue(absentStudentID);
            }
            TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper.presentList.clear();
            TakeAttendanceRecyclerViewHelper.absentList.clear();
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Attendance taken successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
        dialog.show();
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        this.finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend setting breakpoints in your code, running it in a debugger, and checking the value of every variable on each line. When you do that, what is the first line in the code you shared that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Also: don't leave `onCancelled` empty, as you're ignoring potential errors that way. At its very least it should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Hi there, you have a lot of loop over there, can you share your Database Structure?